# Running into beginner's trouble styling form button in CSS

Tags: html, css

For some reason I can't style submit form buttons the way I want. 
Here's how they look right now.[image]

This code works for normal buttons but not on form submit buttons.

```
#sprint1, #sprint2, #sprint3, #sprint4, #sprint5  {
    width: 13%;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; 
    font-family: Verdana, "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size:small;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #07526e;
    padding-top: 2px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 16%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    background-color: #467;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

As you can see the gray textboxes look hideous over the blue backgrounds.
I simply cannot go for button tags, which I have no trouble styling at all. But I have to stick with form submit buttons because they trigger a PHP function that I can't get normal buttons to do.

How do I rid these gray boxes and have the text over the blue buttons instead? Thanks very much!
Here's my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sg26raqL/)

Comment: You are only applying styles to the form, apply them to the input, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input[type=submit] {
    background-color:transparent;
   border:none;
}
```

This is how you apply styling to inputs. In your fiddle, you only applied styles to the `<form>`

*edit*

My example above makes the button transparent. My actual advice would be to apply the form's styling to the input to make the input blue without border, etc.